# Auto Revoke Permissions settings panel missing on some apps (Android 11 API/System)

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm trying to whitelist some of my enterprise apps to avoid the auto-reset of runtime permissions, because they are background applications and users do not interact very often with them.

But it seems (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170968725) that a new manifest attribute
" `autoRevokePermissions` "
isn't working (anymore or for now, I don't know because its new on API lvl 30 BUT its also not working  AND bypassed by system...).

So I'm trying to ask user permisison for this action, like explained here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#auto-reset-permissions-unused-apps

My problem is, on some of the apps, this section of settings is totally gone.
No switch or information when I dive to permissions settings.
I install them from Android Studio
I've updated targetSdkVersion on all, the configurations seems similar...

Does anyone know why I encounter this issue ?

Is there a third way to put this new setting off ?
I'm trying with `packageManager.setAutoRevokeWhitelisted` but
`java.lang.SecurityException: Caller must either hold android.permission.WHITELIST_AUTO_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS or be the installer on record`
... and don't know how to do those)

Thx for the possibles answers, clues or bypasses^^

(and really sorry for bad english ;)

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Does anyone know that why? Could it be conflicting with another permission or sth?

Comment: Official answer from Google dev Team : when the switch is gone from settings, it seems that the app is already whitelisted (details and source in response below)

Comment: I confused because they respond me kind of different way: "Please test it on the next public release and let us know if you are still having issues." https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182822816

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got an official answer from Google developpers Team :

"*The toggle is disabled for some apps that perform a background service, including device admin apps
Whenever the toggle is hidden/disabled the app is already exempted from auto revoke*"

Source : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172325509

My problem is finally solved by itself !

Comment: Thanks for mentioned. I've encountered this issue with a Device Admin app that has background services.

Comment: I also read this but on some devices the toggle is very much present. I ask myself how I should know to prompt the user to disable this setting. My app implements a foreground service. on android 11 the setting is absent, on android 12 it is suddenly present. not sure if this will hold true on all types of devices. I would love if isAutorevokeWithelisted actually returned the truth

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps:

1.setAutoRevokeWhitelisted:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.setAutoRevokeWhitelisted(getPackageName(), true);
boolean result = pm.isAutoRevokeWhitelisted(); // result should be true
```

2.in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WHITELIST_AUTO_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS" />
```

3.sign your app with platform key (see [example](https://codechacha.com/en/android-sign-app-with-platform-key/)), use in build.gradle app:

```
signingConfigs {
        sign_platform {
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('platform.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'platform'
        }
}

defaultConfig {
   signingConfig signingConfigs.sign_platform
}
```

Comment: or set it on the settings on your device: Settings-> Apps -> YourApp -> Permissions -> Remove permissions if app isn't used

Comment: It is good to know that system application features can be emulated in this way, but it is not possible to publish the app in the Play Store this way.

Comment: Hi, I've already tried steps 1 and 2 but my probleme seems that there is an internal and maybe poorly-documented mechanics which hide the settings section when app is auto whitelisted (more details and source in response below)