# How can I disable the Android 11's auto-reset permissions in android application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-permissions

Since Android 11, there has been a system feature where it resets app permissions after a certain amount of time has passed and you haven't used the app.

I know you can turn it off on most apps, by the user itself like the screenshot below :

[image: auto revoke by user]

and also it seems to turn back on when there are app or system updates.

**How can I disable this function in my app by code or sth else?**

Comment: I'm not sure but its a system default feature from Android 11 and you cannot disable it.

Comment: It might helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144816/check-if-remove-permissions-if-app-is-unused-is-disabled-for-a-particular-app

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641725/15749574

Answer (score 4):

Well, I doubt there is an easy way.
If your app is a device policy controller, it will not be set to hibernation ([System exemptions from hibernation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/app-hibernation#system-exemption)) or, if your app is a [default handler](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/default-handlers) for messages, phone, browser etc.

What you can do, is to [ask the user](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/app-hibernation#user-exemption) to disable auto revoke for your app. But you might have to do that after updates as well, if the system resets this privilege on your app (so your problem won't be solved).

The permissions you request in your app manifest (`android:required="true"`) should never be revoked. But of course you cannot request every kind of permission that way. Some need to be requested explicitly.

Apps using background services are whitelisted automatically as stated [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172325509#comment6). So you can declare a background service, if this is appropriate for you. But if there is nothing to be done, I could imagine, that the system removes your app from whitelist. (I didn't test all of it)

If you see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641725/5369727) you can also try

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
pm.setAutoRevokeWhitelisted(getPackageName(), true);
boolean result = pm.isAutoRevokeWhitelisted(); // result should be true
```

and this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WHITELIST_AUTO_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS" />
```

But I actually doubt it works.

Comment: thanks for your response, I',d surely test them and update this post if needed.
I'm Starting with Background service as @İlyas Yıldırım has also mentioned it

Comment: android.permission.WHITELIST_AUTO_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS only allowed for system apps

Answer (score 0):

i found article for your subject. It's says,

> "The toggle is disabled for some apps that perform a background
> service, including device admin apps Whenever the toggle is
> hidden/disabled the app is already exempted from auto revoke"

[Link to the article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648331/auto-revoke-permissions-settings-panel-missing-on-some-apps-android-11-api-syst)

You can examine this if you want. I hope it helps you.